# Parallelismus mit Substantiv und Adjektiv in „nicht nur … sondern“

Tags: adjective, noun, parallelism

> (a) Unsere Meinung in der Öffentlichkeit zu äußern ist nicht nur möglich, sondern unser Recht.
>
> (b) Unsere Meinung in der Öffentlichkeit zu äußern ist nicht nur möglich, sondern **auch** unser Recht.

Sind die beiden Sätze grammatikalisch richtig? Ist es ein Problem, dass hier ein Substantiv mit einem Adjektiv gleichgesetzt wird?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wie schon von in den anderen Antworten gesagt, sind beide Sätze grammatikalisch vollkommen korrekt.

Eine Gleichstellung hängt jedoch rein vom Inhalt ab und nicht von der *Wortart*. In diesem Fall ist *Recht* nicht als zu besitzender Gegenstand zu sehen, sondern als reine *Eigenschaft*. Also stehen sich hier zwei Eigenschaften gegenüber, was absolut rechtens ist.

Die passiert meist dann, wenn es für bestimmte Wörter keine entsprechenden Formen in anderen Wortarten gibt. So lässt sich *schön* zwar in *Schönheit* umwandeln, bleibt aber nach wie vor eine Eigenschaft und wird nicht zu einem handelbaren Gegenstand.

Also in kurz: Wenn ein Nomen für eine Eigenschaft steht, darf es einem Adjektiv gegenübergestellt werden. Das gilt auch für *Tätigkeits*-Nomen, die man einem Verb gegenüberstellt. Hier triumphiert der Inhalt über die Grammatik.

Comment: Ich störe mich ein bisschen am Begriff »Eigenschaft«. Eine _Eigen_-schaft muss doch irgendeiner Sache als Merkmal _eignen_. Welcher Sache eignet das Recht? Und: Wäre dann ein Satz wie »Die Frucht ist nicht nur rund, sondern auch eine Orange« in deinen Augen eigentlich grammatikalisch falsch? Hat ein derartiges Stilmittel nicht sogar einen Namen? Ich komme nicht drauf.

Comment: @bsumirak In deinem Beispiel »Die Frucht ist nicht nur rund, sondern auch eine Orange« wird (auch wenn es unlogisch klingt) *Orange* als Eigenschaft für *Frucht* genutzt. Es scheint zwar logisch das *Orange* keine *Eigenschaft* ist, es kann aber als solche verwendet werden. Dies gilt für theoretisch alle Nomen ,da sie ja sagen WAS etwas ist. Das Obst *kann* eine Orange sein, muss es aber nicht. Das Obst kann auch süß sein, muss es aber nicht. Das *süß* definitiv eine Eigenschaft ist, sollte jedem klar sein. Und wenn man etwas länger darüber nach denkt, gilt das hier auch für Orange.

Comment: Dieses Stilmittel wurde von Heinz Erhard arg ausgebeutet. Allerdings fällt mir gerade kein schlagendes Beispiel ein.

Answer (score 2):

Grammatikalisch sind beide Sätze grundsätzlich korrekt, allerdings sind sie inhaltlich nicht sehr sauber!

Die beiden Komponenten, die mit *nicht nur* und *sondern* gegenübergestellt werden, sollten sich in ihrer Bedeutung voneinander abheben.

*Das Recht haben etwas zu tun* sagt ja schon, dass es *möglich* ist.

> Die Suppe ist nicht nur wohlschmeckend, sondern auch lecker.

Man nennt das „doppelt gemoppelt“.

Ein gutes Beispiel für eine inhaltlich passende Verwendung:

> Unsere Meinung in der Öffentlichkeit zu äußern ist nicht nur möglich,
> sondern (auch) unsere Pflicht!

---

> Ist es ein Problem, dass hier ein Substantiv mit einem Adjektiv gleichgesetzt wird?

Das kann tatsächlich zum Problem werden. Unter Umständen kann eine solche Verbindung sehr seltsam klingen. Dafür lassen sich aber keine Faustregeln aufstellen.

Comment: Servus und willkommen beim Stackexchange der deutschen Sprache. Du kannst eine [tour] der Seite nehmen; bei Fragen steht dir das [help] zur Seite. Der Fragesteller hat explizit nur nach grammatikalisch gefragt, demnach gehen deine inhaltlichen Einwände eigentlich am Punkt vorbei – es ist aber eine schöne Ironie, dass du ausgerechnet durch das Ersetzen von *Recht* durch *Pflicht* einen inhaltlich sauberen Satz aufkommen siehst. Übrigens: Monospace-Auszeichnung sollte hier die große Ausnahme sein, Zitate und Kursiv ist wesentlich besser. Wir reden ja nicht über Codes ;)

Comment: Genau genommen tun wir das sehr wohl.

Comment: Über Codes reden?

Comment: Ja, über Codes reden...

Comment: Auf SO vielleicht; hier reichlich selten ;)

Comment: Das Beispiel mit _wohlschmeckend_ und _lecker_ fällt tatsächlich unter "doppelt gemoppelt" (woher kommt eigentlich dieser Ausdruck?), aber das Beispiel in der ursprünglichen Frage nicht.

Comment: Aus dem Recht, ein Millionenerbe auszuschlagen, folgt nicht die Möglichkeit es zu tun, und so ist es auch mit der Meinungsfreiheit in der Öffentlichkeit.

Answer (score -1):

Beide Sätze sind korrekt. Im zweiten wird der Teil nach dem Komma mehr betont. Siehe zu der Verwendung von *auch* auch die Erläuterung in Section 2.6.1 *Modal* *particles* *in* *statements* in dem Buch von Martin Durrell *Using German* , 2nd edition.

Comment: In genau dem Beispiel empfinde ich, dass das "auch" den Satz mildert, nicht betont. Der erste ist stärker. Er besagt, dass es unser Recht *ist*. Der andere sagt nur, dass das nun eben halt auch so ist.

Comment: Ich bin da anderer Meinung. Ich finde, _auch_ wirkt in dem zweiten Satz wie _sogar_.

Comment: Ich finde *sogar* verstärkt klar, bei *auch* habe ich eher das Gefühl der Verwässerung (Füllwort), aber vielleicht liegt das an der Gegenüberstellung der beiden Sätze, was ja im normalen Sprachgebrauch nicht passiert. Vielleicht sollte man die Antwort kürzen? Das macht sie natürlich sehr kurz, gebe ich zu, aber die Betrachtung zur Wirkung von *auch* geht über die ursprüngliche Frage hinaus. Vielleicht wäre stattdessen besser etwas zum Substantiv-Adjektiv-Verhältnis zu ergänzen.

Comment: Um noch eine weitere Meinung beizutragen, ich finde den Satz ganz ohne _auch_ bzw. _sogar_ seltsam (soll heißen, nicht eindeutig grammatisch). Daher kann ich auch nicht sagen, ob _0_ oder _auch_ stärker ist; auf jeden Fall aber ist _sogar_ stärker als _auch_.